# Monitor a process for actions applied on a file

Tags: windows, file, process

I want to monitor a process in windows to check what actions it performs on a particular file including renaming it, or encrypt it. I want to generate events for these actions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: What kind of events you want to generate, which tools do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easier to monitor the file than the process. Take a look at FileSystemWatcher class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` has lousy granularity though.